# Proving that $a_kA^k+a_{k-1}A^{k-1}+\cdots +a_1A+a_0I = 0_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been studying linear algebra and came across this question that I have no general idea how to solve. The question is as follows.

> Let $A$ be an $n×n$ diagonalizable matrix with distinct eigenvalues $λ_1,λ_2,λ_3$. Suppose $p(λ)=a_kλ^k+a_{k−1}λ^{k−1}+\cdots+a_1λ+a_0$  is a polynomial such that $p(λ_j)=0$ for each $j=1,2,3$. Prove that:
> $$a_kA^k+a_{k-1}A^{k-1}+\cdots +a_1A+a_0I = 0_n$$
> where $0_n$ denotes the $n×n$ zero matrix.

Any sort of guidance on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show that the characteristic = minimal polynomial $(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)$ for $A$ divides $p$.

Comment: "characteristic = minimal polynomial"???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p(x)$ has at least three roots $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, it may be written as $$p(x) = (x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)q(x)$$ where $q(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $3$ less than that of $p(x)$.

$A$ is diagonalizable, so its minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors, the roots of which are the eigenvalues of $A$. So the minimal polynomial $m_A(x) = (x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)$

Clearly, $m_A(x)$ divides $p(x)$. Moreover, $$p(x) = m_A(x)q(x)$$

We know that $m_A(A) = 0_n$, i.e. the zero matrix. This helps us conclude $p(A) = 0_n$ from the above relation!

Answer (score 2):

We have $A = T D T^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal with $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal. Now $p(D)$ is diagonal, with $p(\lambda_i)$ on the diagonal. So $p(D)=0$. Now notice that $p(A) = T p(D) T^{-1}$.